# Check if a vector satisfies a certain equation

Tags: matrices, vectors

Let $S = \{M \in M_3(\mathbb{Z})|M^T \Omega M = \Omega \}$ where $\Omega = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}$.

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $x^2+y^2=z^2$. I have to show that the vector

$\begin{bmatrix}
   x'\\
   y'\\
z'
\end{bmatrix}=M\begin{bmatrix}
   x\\
   y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}$

satisfies the same equation for every $M \in S$.

If I did understand the exercise correctly, I'll have to show that for every $M \in S$:

$M^T\begin{bmatrix}
   x'\\
   y'\\
z'
\end{bmatrix}M=\begin{bmatrix}
   x'\\
   y'\\
z'
\end{bmatrix}$

Did I have to switch the $\Omega$ with my new vector? Is that right? I think I somehow misunderstood the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

no, the exercise that you typed just means this: For a column vector $v$ with entries $x,y,z,$ the quadratic form $x^2 + y^2 - z^2$ is just given by
$$ v^T \Omega v  $$
as this is a 1 by 1 matrix, that is, a number. All the exercise mentions is this: since $\Omega = M^T \Omega M,$  we find
$$ v^T \Omega v = v^T M^T \Omega M v = (Mv)^T \Omega (Mv) = v'^T \Omega v' \; , \;$$
where i mean $v'$ to be the column vector $v' = Mv,$ with elements $x',y',z'.$

Meanwhile, from Magnus, given integers with $\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma = 1$ and $\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta$ even, we get an automorphism matrix for the diagonal matrix with elements ordered $-1,1,1$ as

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} \left( \alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2 \right) & \alpha \beta + \gamma \delta & \frac{1}{2} \left( \alpha^2 - \beta^2 + \gamma^2 - \delta^2 \right) \\
\alpha \gamma + \beta \delta &\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma  &\alpha \gamma - \beta \delta \\
\frac{1}{2} \left( \alpha^2 + \beta^2 - \gamma^2 - \delta^2 \right) & \alpha \beta - \gamma \delta & \frac{1}{2} \left( \alpha^2 - \beta^2 - \gamma^2 + \delta^2 \right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Next, we need to interchange first and third columns and first and third rows.

$$
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} \left( \alpha^2 - \beta^2 - \gamma^2 + \delta^2 \right) & \alpha \beta - \gamma \delta & \frac{1}{2} \left( \alpha^2 + \beta^2 - \gamma^2 - \delta^2 \right) \\
\alpha \gamma - \beta \delta &\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma  &\alpha \gamma + \beta \delta \\
\frac{1}{2} \left( \alpha^2 - \beta^2 + \gamma^2 - \delta^2 \right) & \alpha \beta + \gamma \delta & \frac{1}{2} \left( \alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2 \right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
This gives all such $M$ with positive determinant.

For example, $\alpha = 9, \beta = 4, \gamma = 2, \delta = 1,$ I get
$$
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
31 & 34 & 46  \\
14 &17&22 \\
 34& 38 & 51 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If I then take column vector $v$ with elements $(3,4,5)$ which is a Pythagorean triple, I get a column vector with elements $459,220,509$
This should be a Pythagorean triple as well. $459^2 + 220^2 = 259081.$ Then $509^2 = 259081.$ Hooray!

Comment: Sorry, I have a few doubts:

1. I see how you get the form: $v^T \Omega v$ and how this is the same as $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$. But shouldn't it be equal to 0? Since $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$ I thought that $v^T \Omega v = 0$?

2. The notation: does x' just for another component or does the ' have a special meaning?$